Spark code for NLP processing for china data
I am using pySpark and used jieba for china data. I have have UDF in code and did broadcast but column enriching is taking hours and hours for 5 million record. I am clueless what we need to here to improve the performance here.
dictionary_sample = {
'China': [
    {
        'category': 'Beverage',
        'subcategory': 'Carbonates',
        'sub_subcategory': 'Ale',
        'search_keywords': ['Ale', 'Ginger Ale', 'Schweppes Ginger Ale', 'Brewed Ale', 'Schweppes姜啤酒']
    },
    {
        'category': 'Beverage',
        'subcategory': 'Carbonates',
        'sub_subcategory': 'Brewed Soda',
        'search_keywords': ['Brewed Soda', 'Brewed Creaming Soda', 'Burgundee Creaming Soda', '酿造的苏打水', '冲泡奶油苏打', '勃艮第奶油汽水']
    }
]

}
dictionary size is around 200 MB
    def match_keywords_text(self, country, tokenized_text, nested_dict):
    if country not in nested_dict or tokenized_text is None:
        return []

    #already did lower and strip while creating
    # tokenized_text_set = set(token.strip().lower() for token in tokenized_text if token and token.strip())
    tokenized_text_set = set(tokenized_text)
    matched_category = []
    for entry in nested_dict[country]:
        search_keywords = entry.get('search_keywords', [])
        if search_keywords is None:
            search_keywords = []
        search_keywords_set = set(search_keywords)

        if any(token in search_keywords_set for token in tokenized_text_set):
            matched_category.append(entry['category'])

    if not matched_category:
        return []

    return list(set(matched_category))

